# DVI-D to VGA Adapter "Input Not Supported" on Startup

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, dvi

I've been tasked with increasing the number of monitors from 1 to 3 for a PC.  This machine originally had a DVI-D connection straight to the monitor from the PC.  My knowledge of DVI cables was not great so ended up getting a DVI-D to VGA adapter.  This DVI-D to VGA adapter connected from the PC to a VGA Video Splitter (4 ports), the VGA cables would then come from the Splitter, to the monitors.

Now, this set up only works if I let the booting up process complete whilst the DVI-D cable is plugged directly from the PC to the monitor.  I then take the DVI-D cable out, then plug the DVI-D to VGA adapter in.  Once the adapter is plugged in after booting is complete, the 3 monitors display correctly.
If the DVI-D to VGA adapter is plugged in and connected to all three monitors during the startup process, the error message "Input Not Supported" appears.  Is there anyway I can get the set up I want to work, without having to plug in the DVI cable first and let the booting process complete?  The PC has a DVI port and a HDMI port.  I have not tried anything with the HDMI yet.

Items I am using for this set up:

- 4x VGA Cables
- 1x StarTech.com DVI-D to VGA Active Adapter Converter Cable
- 1x StarTech.com 4 Port Wall Mount VGA Video Splitter
- 3x Acer V6 Series V196LB 19" 1280 x 1024 5ms VGA LED Monitor

This PC is not my own as it's externally owned. It boots up to Linux OS that I can't navigate freely.  However, I can get into the BIOS settings.

Comment: What are the GPU and motherboard?

Comment: I will get those for you if I can, I'll be back to you shortly.

Comment: Without knowing your splitter, VGA monitors can indicate which resolution and freq they support, but that's close to impossible if you use such a splitter because it would have to combine that information, which would require a computation and then reporting an appropriate compromise to the graphics card. So I would work with the thesis that no such communication takes place and in this case, an appropriate reolution may have to be set in the operating system. Don't have experience with such a setup but I suspect that to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Does anyone think I should perhaps just buy a DVI-D splitter so the signal type stays the same at least?  This would mean no DVI-D to VGA.